# Change function name in Laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, function, laravel, laravel-4

```
{!!   Form::file('bannername[]',
    array('id'=>'bannername',
    'class'=>'uploadResBanner',
   'onchange'=>'readURL(this)' )) !!}
<img class="bannerImgsShop" id="bannerImg<% $index %>" src="{!! asset('UploadedImages/upload.png') !!}" />

<input type="button" class="actionAddDelete" value="Add Banner"  ng-click="addInput()">
```

**Question:** When I click on Add Banner Button `'readURL(this)'` should add 1 like `'readURL1(this)`, when I click again at Add Banner '`readURL(this)` should be '`readURL2(this)`.
As well as I need `readURL1(this), readURL2(this), readURL3(this) ....`

My Script is this

```
<script>
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#logoimg')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(142)
                        .height(142);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to call the AngularJS function or wanted to call Laravel function ?

Comment: is your function working in js?

Comment: Can't you keep the count in your javascript function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't You define global variable like `var click;` and iterate this variable when function call, and in body of `readURL(this)` do:

```
function readURL(this){
    click++;
    switch(true){
       case click == 1:
         readUrl1(this);
         break;
       case click == 2:
         readUrl1(this);
         break;
    }
}
```

sorry, syntax may be wrong. Hope this help